# Variable is getting Overwritten by the subsequent variable in printf

Tags: c, loops, variables, output, printf

I am not getting the complete word of the variable , it is overridden by the next element
The code goes this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct item
{
    struct data
    {
        char content[10][20];
    } details;
    struct item *next;
};
typedef struct item product;
void display(struct data *variable)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct data *v = variable;
    while (strcmp(v->content[i], "END") != 0)
    {
        printf("Element : %s \n", v->content[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
struct data *init_Tshirt()
{
    char usage_type[20];
    struct data *new_data = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    printf("Enter The Usage type(Sports_Usage/Casuals_Usage): ");
    scanf("%s", usage_type);
    sprintf(new_data->content[0], "Usage Type = %s", usage_type);
    strcpy(new_data->content[1], "END"); // used as a deliminator
    return new_data;
}
struct data *init_Saree()
{
    char material_type[20];
    struct data *new_data = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    printf("Enter The Material(Cotton_Material/Silk_Material): ");
    scanf("%s", material_type);  
    sprintf(new_data->content[0], "Material Type = %s", material_type);
    strcpy(new_data->content[1], "END"); // used as a deliminator
    return new_data;
}
int main()
{
    struct data *variable1 = init_Tshirt();
    display(variable1);
    struct data *variable2 = init_Saree();
    display(variable2);
}
```

And the output is

```
Enter The Usage type(Sports_Usage/Casuals_Usage): Sports_Usage
Element : Usage Type = Sports_END
Enter The Material(Cotton_Material/Silk_Material): Cotton_Material       
Element : Material Type = CottEND
```

And i Expect the output to be

```
Enter The Usage type(Sports_Usage/Casuals_Usage): Sports_Usage
Element : Usage Type = Sports_Usage
Enter The Material(Cotton_Material/Silk_Material): Cotton_Material       
Element : Material Type = Cotton_Material
```

I dont know why the output string is overwritten.
Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried moving the `struct data` definition outside of the `struct item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you write a string into the first element (first row) of the field *content* using *sprintf*, you write also into its second element (second row) when the string is longer than nineteen characters.

[image]

You need to increase the length of *content* and check that the string fits, or simply truncate it using *snprintf* which takes an additional size parameter.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: It actually worked ! But can you be more precise ? I am not understanding How can first element be stored in the next element

Comment: And if it is really stored in the next element how can it get printed along with the first element

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya That's because in memory the first byte of the second element (second row) comes directly after the last byte of the first element (first row). The *sprintf* function just keeps on writing characters until a null character is written.

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I have added an image to illustrate what happens.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you :)

Comment: Really appreciate the effort man! Thank you